# Generic way to send an array collection containing only a part of a more complex structure

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

Let's say a program like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Numbers;
    public char Letters;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var mc = new MyClass[5];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            mc[i].Numbers = i + 1;
            mc[i].Letters = (char) (i + 65);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's suppose an 'X' method that requires ALL the numbers contained in the object `mc`, in a separate array, that's sent as a parameter.

My first idea is a for, a new integers array, and copy one by one onto its respective position. But, what if the `MyClass` gets different, now it has strings and floats, and I wanna pull out the strings, now the for has to be completely redefined in its inside part to create the needed array for another 'X' method.

I know of cases where Linq helps a lot, for example, generics for Sum, Average, Count and another numeric functions, and of course, it's combination with lambda expressions.

I'm wondering if something similar exists to make the above arrays of `MyClass` (and anothers of course) in a faster-generic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C# 4.0, then you may use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

```
class MyClass
{
    public dynamic Numbers;
    public char Letters;
}
```

EDIT: *based on comments*

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
int[] arr = mc.Select(a => a.Numbers).ToArray<int>();
```

or without casting

```
int[] arr = mc.Select(a => a.Numbers).ToArray();
```

Comment: I see your point. However, the idea isn't this. Remember the for part. I can do a var d = new dynamic[mc.Length]; for (var i = 0; i < mc.Length; i++) { d[i] = mc[i].<TheElement>; } and then pass the `d` parameter to the 'X' method. dynamic helps on some generalization, however, the for-loop still exists. Can something be done to delete the for?

Comment: @mishamosher, my bad, I didn't get your question properly.

Comment: To reproduce the thing what I want like, get this idea... something like `mc.ToArray(arr=>arr.Numbers)`. And that's supposed to return a `int[]` array of mc's size and with the numbers of mc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use LINQ, you can do something like the following:

```
int [] numbers = mc.Select<MyClass, int>(m => mc.Number).ToArray();
```

To make it more generic than that, it gets a bit more complicated, and you may need reflection, or dynamic objects. A simple example with reflection would be:

```
    private TValue[] ExtractFields<TClass, TValue>(TClass[] classObjs, string fieldName)
    {
        FieldInfo fInfo = typeof(TClass).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (fInfo != null && fInfo.FieldType.Equals(typeof(TValue)))
            return classObjs.Select<TClass, TValue>(c => (TValue)fInfo.GetValue(c)).ToArray();
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unidentified field, or different field type"); 
    }
```

And then just call it like:

```
int [] fields = ExtractField<MyClass, int>(mc, "Number");
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. But it's a simpler case for what I'm (was) fighting for. See Habib.OSU edit for clarification. I'm willing to also mark this as an answer, but StackOverflow let's me mark only one response as an answer. +1 to this answer!

Comment: No worries. LINQ to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `Dictionary<int, char>`, or if the data type is unknown then simply `Dictionary<object, object>`

Comment: Because I want an array of a single-strong defined type... I'm not passing the Numbers and Letters at time... I'm passing only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to generate a new array which is detached from the original array, but contains data copied from it, the most generic thing you could do would be to define a method like:

```
  T my_array[];  // The array which holds the real things
  U[] CopyAsConvertedArray<U>(Func<T,U> ConversionMethod);
```

That would allow one to generate a new array which extracts items from the original using any desired method.